# How to solve JFRAME not responding

Tags: java

Here is my code
   [enter image description here][1]

How to solve JFrame not responding.

I am getting JFrame Error after clicking on the button and the code is running correctly but the frame is showing error as not responding is anyone knows about this. I have added the image.
 adding same info because SO not allowing to post I am getting JFrame Error after clicking on the button and the code is running correctly but the frame is showing error as not responding is anyone knows about this. I have added the image.

Comment: You are running your code in the same thread your GUI is running in. As this means everything is just done sequentially the GUI will not update until your code is finished running -> JFrame is "not responding". Run your code in another thread and separate your GUI-logic from your code logic.

Comment: More information is required rather than copying your message twice because you want to get around the content requirement.

Comment: Use Multi threading. Create a separate thread for UI.

Comment: Why are you mixing JavaFX and Swing? The `while-try` isn't going to help you either, as this will block the `Stage`, I'm also kind of scared about how many frames you're going to be creating with this code

Comment: I tried but not successful to create the new thread for my class Speech.

Comment: I have created one more class for the speech from that I am calling the method but still I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Thank for your response I got the solution.